# How to play GSM files in HTML5

Tags: html, audio, gsm

I would like to play a GSM audio file within my HTML5 page

In order to do some testing I created the following piece of code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <audio controls>
        <source src="/home/server/Desktop/audiofile.wav" type="audio/x-wav">
    </audio>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately this code does not work and and the play button is grey.

Details of audio format with `soxi`

```
Input File     : 'audiofile.wav'
Channels       : 1
Sample Rate    : 8000
Precision      : 16-bit
Duration       : 00:00:04.16 = 33280 samples ~ 312 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 6.82k
Bit Rate       : 13.1k
Sample Encoding: GSM
```

Do you understand where the problem is?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp

```
HTML Audio - Media Types

File Format
Media Type
MP3 audio/mpeg 
Ogg audio/ogg 
Wav audio/wav
```

if you dont have a GSM codec on your machine it will not work however, so you'll need to grab one 
mega Codec pack contains GSM 6.10
http://www.free-codecs.com/ACE_Mega_CoDecS_Pack_download.htm

Comment: Tried already!! Yes the container is wav but the file is encoded in GSM

Comment: mmm. This is not an option. I do not want to force people to install new software on their pcs

Comment: GSM is not a standard codec, your other option would be to convert 'Samples' of the GSM into standard WAVs

Comment: I agree, however I have literally more than a million files and the conversion is not an option because the amount of space needed to store them will be immense. Can I use another format which does not require too much space and which is supported natively by HTML5? I recall that is speech audio so MP3 is not an option for obvious reasons

Comment: I am afraid I dont know exactly HOW you would do this but if the host will let you install the codec on the server I know real-time trans-coding is possible and is used by some video sites to give html5 friendly previews of encoded video formats.